# Dynamic synchronous import with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, synchronous

Is there any way to make a blocking dynamic import using [`import()`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-) or something similar? It's an uncommon scenario, but I want to conditionally import polyfills, so I don't want to execute any more scripts until the polyfills have come in.

I can think of some alternatives:

- wrap everything else in the callback (this could be a problem if there's other scripts chunked out.. they could run before the polyfills arrive)
- have a separate script tag for the polyfills, but still have to do something weird to only load it in certain browsers.
- use [polyfill.io](http://polyfill.io)

Also I guess blocking XHTML (aka "JAX" :p) requests are deprecated even though I feel like this is a reasonable use-case.. so, is there a 'recommended' way to do something like this?

Comment: This may help https://philipwalton.com/articles/loading-polyfills-only-when-needed/